# Qu'est-ce que je peux faire pendant mon séjour en France pour améliorer mon français au maximum ?

Tags: oral, france

Je voudrais poser une question primordiale pour tous les francophones qui habitent en France. La réponse à cette question pourra aider tous les étudiants du français dans le futur.

Bon, je suis un étudiant de la langue française. J’ai commencé il y a un an et maintenant j’ai l'opportunité d'aller en France pour un mois ou plus. Donc, je suis en train de vraiment réfléchir à comment je peux améliorer mon français pendant mon séjour là-bas au maximum. Que puis-je faire pour vraiment profiter en France ?

J'ai quelques idées :

1. Je peux aller à l'école de langue française pour prendre des cours intensifs.
2. Je peux habiter avec une famille d’accueil.
3. Je peux voyager dans toute la France.

Je n’aime pas la première option, parce que premièrement ça coutera beaucoup et deuxièmement j’ai déjà une très bonne base en français. De plus, je peux apprendre la grammaire moi-même. Aussi, dans les écoles comme ça, il y a toujours tous les autres anglophones qui parlent anglais tout le temps. La deuxième option m’intéresse beaucoup parce que j’aurais beaucoup d'opportunités pour pratiquer mon français toute la journée ; ou j’espère que je l’aurai.

Bref, la seule chose dont j'ai besoin est de pratiquer mon français oral.

La question :

Qu’est-ce que je peux faire en France pour pratiquer mon français au maximum. Aussi, qu’est-ce que vous pensez à propos des 3 options que j'ai mentionnées ci-dessus ?

Si votre réponse est « aller parler avec les gens », dites-moi comment je peux faire. Où sont les endroits où il est facile d'« allumer les grandes conversations » avec n’importe qui ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Il y a 22 régions en France, des départements et territoire outre-mer, avec parfois des accents locaux très marqués, comme ceux du sud de la Loire.

On peut envisager de commencer par PARIS, essayer d'y trouver une famille d'accueil, et prendre contact avec [L'Alliance Française](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alliance_fran%C3%A7aise) (pas obligatoirement pour suivre tous les cours, mais pour bénéficier de l'expérience d'insertion et avoir toutes les adresses utiles, les démarches à accomplir) se familiariser avec le quotidien et les règles à suivre.

Ensuite, c'est selon votre envie, peut-être un job d'été, quelques escapades au bord de mer, en montagne, selon les opportunités ; vous y rencontrerez des gens de toutes sortes, comme partout.

En revanche, essayer de trouver un cours de théâtre amateur (on en trouve dans les maisons des jeunes et de la culture, et certaines associations municipales).
C'est sûrement le meilleur moyen de nouer de vrais contacts avec des gens qui aiment et parlent le français correctement.

Bravo pour votre envie de francophonie, et à bientôt dans l'hexagone.

Comment: Au niveau de l'option voyage, le _must_ - pardon - est de pratiquer le covoiturage, sans concurrence pour rencontrer des français et bavarder avec eux : http://www.covoiturage.fr (publicité gratuite).

Comment: Si tu voyages, n'hésite pas à aussi passer dans un pays voisin où il y a aussi des francophones (comme la Belgique, juste au nord), il y aura là aussi plein de gens ravis de t'accueillir.

Answer (score 2):

cl-r a très bien répondu à la question, je n'aurais pas fait mieux.

J'ajouterai seulement qu'à défaut de trouver une famille d'accueil, tu peux aussi passer par le site [CouchSurfing](http://www.couchsurfing.org/). Attention tout de même au choix de la personne, essaie de viser quelqu'un qui a déjà de l'expérience dans l'accueil et avec une bonne réputation. C'est un moyen économique et stimulant pour rencontre des gens, et s'immerger dans leur culture.